# How to get the Total Sale of every month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to show sale of every month on a jquery bar called Flot & here is my query

```
$q = $db->getRows("SELECT date AS dates,
COUNT(id) AS sales FROM orders 
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date`", 
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, ["$year-01-01", "$year-12-31"]);
```

Here is how I'm utilizing my query

```
$views = array_fill(1, (int) 12, 0);

foreach ($q as $viewed) {
        $the_day = (int) substr($viewed['dates'], -2);  // get the day from the date

        $views[$the_day] = $viewed['sales'];
}
 return $views;
```

This is the response of my code

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [0] => 1
)
```

It should show the last [0] => 1 value into the 9th month.
Where I'm wrong in this query?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY month(date)` and in the select use `month(date)`. Then just fetch the results and output.

Comment: Your own comment in the code says why this is wrong

Comment: Based on the subject line, I would have expected to see a sum() aggregate in there somewhere.

Comment: You can use `extract(MONTH FROM date)` in the GROUP BY clause. Even though you are using the where clause to limit for one particluar year, I'd also add `extract(YEAR FROM date)` to the group by clause in case you want list several years. See also: http://modern-sql.com/feature/extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain the values directly from the db  eg:

```
  "SELECT 
      month(date) AS month
      , COUNT(id) AS sales 
      FROM orders     
  WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
  GROUP BY month(`date`) 
  ORDER BY month(`date`)"
```